# Query String Redirection using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am converting a static HTML website to a CMS.

The images folder is conflicting with a category name.

So, I would like to redirect all images in **HOWTO** directory like :

```
http://yourdomain.com/howto/images/someimage.jpg
```

to something like :

```
   http://yourdomain.com/howto_imgs/images/someimage.jpg
```

I only want to change the image location and redirect old image URL links so they are displayed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule  ^howto/images/(.*)$  howto_imgs/images/$1  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been looking for a solution since 2 days now. You'r answer did it. Solved it! I really appreciate your taking out the time and giving me a working solution!